# View SQL scripts in Logback

Tags: logback

I have to change the scripts in Logback for the database appender. The documentation says it is found here:classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/dialect. So I opened teh jar file to look for it. The problem is I don't see the classic/src/main/java
I do see ch/qos/logback/classic/db but not dialect. I also only see .class files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem. Found out the sql files really are missing from the downloaded jar files. However, they seem to be in trunk, so you can download them from here:

http://svn.qos.ch/viewvc/logback/trunk/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/dialect/

Answer (score 0):

If you download logback-0.9.29.zip, you can find it in

> logback-0.9.29.zip\logback-0.9.29\logback-classic\src\main\java\ch\qos\logback\classic\db\dialect